# putting hashes values into another hash

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

okay so, im asking 2 questions and putting each user's input into separate hashes. I am using loop to iterate through this multiple times then adding all hashes into an array. 
My question is/where im stuck, how do I assign the sum of values of each hash, to a separate hash of their own.

Here's my code:

```
arr:[]
         (1..n).each do |i|

 hash=Hash.new()

 puts "Please input a value for day # #{i}" 
 hash["day1"]=gets.chomp.to_f

 puts "Please input a value for day # #{i}" 
 hash["day2"]=gets.chomp.to_f

 arr << hash

  end
```

I thought of doing this since this is the method i've been using to collect users input and put them in a hash but it doesn't work:/

```
   hash[:total]= hash.each_value.inject(:+)
```

I basically want to sum each hash and put it into a new hash. is that even possible? it's hard cause I would have to do it outside of the block but then the system wouldn't recognize the variables:/

Comment: Show your hashes, please.

Comment: You might write "okay so, im asking..." in a text message but it's inappropriate at SO. Read through some of the better questions and answers and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Hash#reduce` method with `Hash#merge`

```
arr = []
3.times do |i|
  hash = Hash.new()
  puts "Please input a value for day # #{i}"
  hash["day1"] = gets.chomp.to_f
  puts "Please input a value for day # #{i}"
  hash["day2"] = gets.chomp.to_f
  arr << hash
end

totals = arr.reduce({}) do |sums, day|
  sums.merge(day) { |_, a, b| a + b }
end

puts totals
# {"day1"=>8.0, "day2"=>11.0}
```